# How to send Mail in a static web project

Tags: javascript, java, html, xhtml

I don't know how to send a email from a simple html form  when a submit button is clicked the data's from the form should be sent to a specified email.
Can some one help me out please.

Comment: You can't; the best you can do is use a `mailto:` URL that would open the mail software and pre-populate the email (but not actually send it). To actually send an email, you would need to have a serverside component.

Comment: Hi there. you need to learn phpmailer first :)

Comment: That's not true, although a type of serverside component is required somewhere in the process, there are many solutions to work around this such as using parse with a mail service like sendgrid; however, I personally think formspree is the easiest and most effective